# mudflap without "export"

Tags: c, bash, shell, gcc

Is it possible to set the variable MUDFLAP_OPTIONS inside the C program rather than having to export it from bash ?

```
myuser@linux:~$ export MUDFLAP_OPTIONS="-mode-check -viol-abort -internal-checking -heur-stack-bound -heur-start-end -verbose-violations -crumple-zone=32"
myuser@linux:~$ gcc -fmudflap -funwind-tables -lmudflap -rdynamic myprogram.c
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
static char *var = "MUDFLAP_OPTIONS=-mode-check -viol-abort -internal-checking -heur-stack-bound -heur-start-end -verbose-violations -crumple-zone=32";
putenv(var);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to export to anything but the program you want to start. Like this:

```
VARNAME=value ./program
```

So for your case:

```
MUDFLAP_OPTIONS="-mode-check -viol-abort -internal-checking -heur-stack-bound -heur-start-end -verbose-violations -crumple-zone=32" ./myprogram
```

Comment: Your edit is wrong; the original was actually correct, though I'm not sure how helpful it is to condense two lines into one really long line that you need to repeat all the time. When Mudflap is compiled into your program, it will check the environment variable at runtime to determine its options; it's not controlled at compile time.

Comment: @Brian: saw your comment on the other answer. Reverted. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Mudflap is probably reading the options before `main` is called, so you won't have a chance to write the options to the environment before it reads them.

Why not just write a wrapper script, that sets the options and invokes your executable?

```
#!/bin/sh
export MUDFLAP_OPTIONS="-mode-check -viol-abort -internal-checking -heur-stack-bound -heur-start-end -verbose-violations -crumple-zone=32"
./my-executable
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why Makefiles exist. gcc will not execute your program for you, nor will it get any environment variables from your code. Instead you need to set this kind of stuff inside of a Makefile, like this:

```
export MUDFLAP_OPTIONS="-mode-check -viol-abort -internal-checking -heur-stack-bound -heur-start-end -verbose-violations -crumple-zone=32"

all:
    gcc -fmudflap -funwind-tables -lmudflap -rdynamic myprogram.c
```

Save this as `Makefile` and simply type `make` to compile your program. You'll never need to remember to export that variable again.

Comment: This is wrong. Mudflap is compiled into your program, and then when your program is run, it checks the `MUDFLAP_OPTIONS` environment variable to determine its runtime settings. So you need to set the environment variable when *running* the program, not when compiling it.

Comment: The `export` should not be necessary in a GNU make file. Also I think using `CFLAGS` and `CC` to select `gcc` pass the flags would be the better approach, by using implicit rules. (`all: myprogram` and `myprogram: myprogram.c` without any extra commands necessary). Still +1 for the use of a make file :)

Comment: @Brian Campbell: this is not at all visible from the question, though. Inside the question `myprogram` does not even get executed :)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED This is why I actually looked up Mudflap's usage before answering; I was going to post the answer about using a Makefile, but decided to check the documentation, and discovered that it's actually reading the environment variable at runtime, not compile time (which would be an odd time to read an environment variable anyhow).

Comment: @Brian: at compile time wouldn't be all too odd in my opinion. After all `gcc` executes other "backend stuff". So controlling that by environment variables would make sense.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Fair enough; I suppose I should say that it's a bad time to read environment variables, not an odd time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Mudflap related additional flags to your make file as below

```
MUDFLAP_OPTIONS+=-fmudflap -fmudflapth -funwind-tables
```

Then link it with -lmudflapth -rdynamic as below

```
LDFLAGS+=-lmudflapth -rdynamic
```

Note: the flag "-fmudflapth" is required only if your code is a multi threaded one. If not you can avoid that flag and while linking use "-lmudflap" instead of "-lmudflapth"

For mudflap help use `MUDFLAP_OPTIONS="-help" ./myexecutablefile`